# Insert query in mysql

Tags: mysql, insert, mysql-5.6

I am using MySQL. I have table like below:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table
(
    first_name VARCHAR(20),
    last_name VARCHAR(20),
    full_name VARCHAR(40)
);
```

Now I want to insert values like below:

```
INSERT INTO test_table
VALUES('raju','pydi',CONCAT(first_name,last_name));
```

I know this will not work, but it illustrates what I want to achieve.

How can I do this with a query? (not a procedure or function or some other).

Comment: Why are you storing fullname?

Comment: I know concat operator we can use in select statement ,but i want to know my question is  possible or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
INSERT INTO test_table
    (first_name,last_name,full_name)
SELECT first_name,last_name
     , CONCAT(coalesce(first_name,''),coalesce(last_name,''))
FROM (
    SELECT 'raju' as FIRST_NAME
          ,'pydi' as LAST_NAME
) AS T;
```

I still think it's a pretty bad idea to store full_name though. You could create a view like:

```
CREATE VIEW TEST_VIEW AS (
    SELECT first_name, last_name
         , CONCAT(coalesce(first_name,''),coalesce(last_name,'')) as full_name
    FROM test_table
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specific the columns `firstname` and `last_name` in your `INSERT` statements. As the [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) `INSERT` documentation says:

> An expression expr can refer to any column that was set earlier in a value list. For example, you can do this because the value for col2 refers to col1, which has previously been assigned:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (col1,col2) VALUES(15,col1*2);
```

> But the following is not legal, because the value for col1 refers to
>   col2, which is assigned after col1:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (col1,col2) VALUES(col2*2,15);
```

**Example:**

```
mysql> INSERT INTO `test`.`new_table`
    -> (`first`,`last`,`full`)
    -> VALUES
    -> ('oNare','Antigua',CONCAT(first,' ',last));
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM test.new_table;
+-------+---------+---------------+
| first | last    | full          |
+-------+---------+---------------+
| oNare | Antigua | oNare Antigua |
+-------+---------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```